# Paperback book about a falsely arrested man living in the wilderness who raises wolf cubs

Tags: identification-request

The book starts with the protagonist, a shop owner, who gets falsely arrested for murder. While he's being taken away in a police car, he manages to escape and runs off into the woods, which happens to be a national park. He lives in a cave near the top of a hill. At some point in the book, he finds 2 wolf cubs and ends up raising them.

I don't recall much of the middle of the book, but this man does end up making trips to town a few times to get some supplies and befriends someone who doesn't judge him for his past.

At the end of the book, the man learns that his name was cleared for murder and that he could stop hiding.

I believe the whole plot takes place in Michigan, USA, but I'm not 100% sure about that.

I discovered the book first at a garage sale. It was a light blue paperback cover. I think it was written in the late 70s.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I misplaced this book.

Comment: I found a book [*Throw Me to the Wolves*](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2019/apr/26/throw-me-to-the-wolves-by-patrick-mcguinness-review) about a man falsely accused of murder, but the titular wolves are only metaphorical, so it's not what you're looking for.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Thanks for the suggestion, but that book is far too new of a publication and takes place in England. I checked it out, it seems like a good read, but sadly it's not the right book.

Answer (score 4):

Self answer. I was doing some research calling up friends and a few librarians. The book I was looking for was *Shadows of the Wolf* by Larry Koesling. From the [Google Books summary](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Shadows_of_the_Wolf.html?id=2xRUYAAACAAJ&redir_esc=y):

> Convicted but innocent man for robbery and murder escapes on his way to prison. The wilderness becomes his refuge . He comes across a cave with a dying she wolf and her pups. When she ends up buying the farm, he raises the pups.

Looks like I was quite off with the year I thought it was written. It was authored in 1995.

Comment: Congrats on finding this! I've added a little information to your answer to make clear to anyone reading this page that it is the right book. (ID requests are actually useful to a lot more people than just the asker; who knows when some internet searcher will come looking for the same book. See also [Guidelines for good story-ID answers](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/839/17).) Don't forget to accept this answer when you can, I think after 48 hours. Nice one :-)